# Error running CellBender - h5py falis to load the DLLs

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, h5py

I have followed the installation steps referring to the documentation [here](https://github.com/broadinstitute/CellBender). And when I run cellbender, I see the following *Error*, please check and suggest what might be the right fix here:

```
(CellBender) C:\Users\user12\Desktop\cellbender_test>cellbender remove-background --input C:\Users\user12\Desktop\feature_bc_matrix.h5 --output C:\Users\user12\Desktop\output.h5 --cuda --expected-cells 5000 --total-droplets-included 20000 --fpr 0.01 --epochs 150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\Scripts\cellbender-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('cellbender', 'console_scripts', 'cellbender')())
  File "c:\users\user12\desktop\cellbender_test\cellbender\cellbender\base_cli.py", line 91, in main
    cli_dict = generate_cli_dictionary()
  File "c:\users\user12\desktop\cellbender_test\cellbender\cellbender\base_cli.py", line 52, in generate_cli_dictionary
    module_cli = importlib.import_module('.'.join(module_cli_str_list))
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\user12\desktop\cellbender_test\cellbender\cellbender\remove_background\cli.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cellbender.remove_background.data.dataset import SingleCellRNACountsDataset
  File "c:\users\user12\desktop\cellbender_test\cellbender\cellbender\remove_background\data\dataset.py", line 10, in <module>
    import anndata
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\lib\site-packages\anndata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._core.anndata import AnnData
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\lib\site-packages\anndata\_core\anndata.py", line 17, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:\Users\user12\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CellBender\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried installing h5py - 3.6.0 and 3.1.0 none of those versions worked in my case. Also, I printed out the import paths and copied the respective files from *h5py*, still no luck.

Comment: The referenced CellBender docs say you install PyTables package before you install the CellBender package. Did you do that? Do you also have h5py installed?

Comment: @kcw78, I did install those packages already. You can check on the process and error stack here: github.com/broadinstitute/CellBender/issues/185

Comment: Bioconda packages require everything else to come from Conda Forge. If you source things from `anaconda` (`defaults`) you’ll get DLL errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the aggravating things when you try to use pytables and h5py at the same time. They both use HDF5 libraries/dlls. You will get that error message when they use different versions. I have the same issue on my system (so I can replicate the errors). First, check the version on your system.

**Check HDF5 version for h5py:**

```
import h5py
print(h5py.version.info)

## Partial output from my system:
Summary of the h5py configuration
---------------------------------    
h5py    3.3.0
HDF5    1.12.0
Python  3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 06:50:17)
```

**Check HDF5 version for pytables:**

```
import tables as tb
print(tb.__version__)
print(tb.hdf5_version)
## Output from my system:
3.6.1
1.10.6
```

As you can see, I have a HDF5 library mismatch between the 2 packages (1.12.0 for h5py and 1.10.6 for pytables). I suspect you are getting h5py as part of pytorch. (It supports HDF5 files.) The solution is installing a pytables version with the same HDF5 version as h5py in pytorch.

Comment: I have checked the versions, but when I install `pytables` using conda, I don't see any package called `tables` in the conda environment. So I think I only have one version of h5py in my environment.

Comment: Pytables is imported with `import tables` (not `import pytables`). Yes, confusing. I add `as tb` to shorten.

Comment: I see when I installed pytables using `conda install -c anaconda pytables`, the package tables==3.7.0 is getting installed. And, I see a mismatch in HDF5 versions for tables and h5py libraries. What do you suggest if the best solution here, as I am installing pytables from conda and h5py using pip, may you once refer to [CellBender](https://cellbender.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html) installation and suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: Here are the versions;
`h5py - 3.8.0` - 
`HDF5 - 1.12.2`
-----------------
`tables - 3.7.0`
Errors out

Upon installing `tables - 3.6.1` -
`HDF5 - 1.10.5`

Comment: That confirms your problem (the `hdf5.dll` versions don't match). PyTables release notes say they renamed the dll to `pytables_hdf5.dll` in v3.6 to avoid this problem. I checked my installation, and that's not what I found. Given you are dealing with multiple packages, I'm hesitant to make any recommendations.